# win 2008 r2 unable to activate "make genunine"

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a copy of windows 2008 r2 which is genuine, I am using it as a developmnt environment. I have it set up as a DC. When I select "Activate windows now" / "Activate windows online" it keeps throwing message "DNS name does not exist".

I suspest this is to do with KMS but unsure how to proceed

Comment: Are you able to clear the dns cache and resolve other common endpoints? Can you get the target IP and tracert to get to the site?

Answer (score 1):

Was this an MSDN or a VLK copy of Windows? If so, see [KB 929826](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929826). The short:

Change the product key to a Multiple Activation Key (MAK) by following these steps:

> 1. Click the Start button, click All Programs, click Accessories, and then right-click
>      Command Prompt.
> 2. Click Run as administrator.
>
>    If you are prompted for an administrator password or for
>      confirmation, type the password or
>      provide confirmation.
> 3. At the command prompt, type the following command, and then press
>      ENTER:
>
>    `slmgr -ipk xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx`
>
>    Note In this command, the `xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx`
>      placeholder represents your MAK product key.